# Real Time location sharing application using react native

Tags: reactjs, geolocation, native

I want to try making an application for location sharing with my friends.

Is it possible using react native geolocation API and firebase?

If not what other approach can i follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Geolocation of ReactNative.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#watchposition

Check the `watchPosition` method, it registers a callback which invokes whenever your location changes, and you will receive a position object.

You should then send this data to firebase.

On all your devices, you should use a listener to listen for changes in your firebase cloud firestore.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Display the location data on your app.

Comment: I tried to use watchPosition inside componentDidMount() function and give an alert whenever position changes. It only works the first time and not after that.

Comment: did you ```enableHighAccuracy```?

Comment: how about ```distanceFilter```? the default can be 100 meters!

Comment: I used distance filter as 1 m .

Comment: I removed  this function :   
     componentWillUnmount()  {   navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId); } . I think it is working fine now. (I have enabled highAccuracy option to True)

Comment: Is it possible to use Parse as an open source substitute for firebase?

Comment: what's stopping you? any backend is a posible solution!